# Make two dataframes to one and aggregate the sums

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
            'value': [100, 300, 150]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'D'],
            'value': [20, 50, 7]})
```

I want to merge these two dataframes to a new dataframe df3 so I get the following result:

[image]

Then I want to have a forth new dataframe df4 where the rows aggregated to sums like

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'C',  'D'],
            'value': [120, 350, 150, 7]})
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the DataFrames together then use a groupby and sum:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df4 = df3.groupby('name').sum().reset_index()
```

Result of `df4`:

```
  name  value
0    A    120
1    B    350
2    C    150
3    D      7
```

Comment: Ty, why the reset_index()?

Comment: Resetting the index ensures that `name` is a column again. If you don't reset the index, then `name` remains the index

Comment: Alternatively `as_index=False` can be passed to `groupby` to keep `name` from becoming an index. `df4 = df3.groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: @DerekO Ty, great help for a newbie like me.

Comment: @DerekO Ty, is there a command to check if name is a column again? Would it be something like df4.info() ?

Comment: you can look at `df4.columns`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is just append

```
df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True).groupby('name')['value'].sum().to_frame()



       value
name       
A       120
B       350
C       150
D         7
```